# C# Add LDAP user to group

Tags: c#, ldap, directoryentry

I am writing the following method to add users on active directory to a custom group in C#.
I have an OU named "SHO Users" and a sub-ou named "SHO Sharepoint User"
All my users are saved under sub-ou.
I do have a group under the first ou "SHO Users" named "Test GRP".
I need to add some of the users to "Test GRP" group with the following code but no luck.
I'll really appreciate for any help.
Thanks

```
public void AddToGroup(string userDn, string groupDn)
{
    try
    {
        DirectoryEntry dirEntry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + groupDn);
        dirEntry.Properties["member"].Add(userDn);
        dirEntry.CommitChanges();
        dirEntry.Close();
    }
    catch (System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryServicesCOMException E)
    {
        //doSomething with E.Message.ToString();

    }
}

protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
string UserId = txtFirstname.Text + " " + txtLastname.Text;
AddToGroup("CN=" + UserId + ",OU=SHO Sharepoint User,OU=SHO Users,dc=test,dc=com", "CN=Test GRP,CN=Groups,DC=test,DC=com");
}
```

Comment: If you're on .Net 3.5 you should utilize the System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement namespace (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement(v=vs.90).aspx).

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not on .Net 3.5 and i think I have no choice just using directoryentry functions

Comment: Does the account running this have permission to add members to the group? From what I recall working with DirectoryEntries was extremely sensitive on this point. You'll need to ensure the application pool identity has this domain permission or you'll need to wrap the call in an impersonation context of a user who does

Comment: I think i do have the appropriate permission to do this because I'm adding users too and it's working fine.

Comment: Do you get an exception in the code block that is commented out?

Comment: I'm not receiving any errors. right after i click on btnAdd_Click my code is creating the user account under AD and it will enable the user,reset the password and at the end i'm calling AddToGroup function but no errors and user is added into AD but not joined to the desired group

Comment: could anyone check my LDAP strings? for AddToGroup i have to provide userDn and groupDN. I'm calling my userDn by "CN=John Smith,OU=SHO Sharepoint User,OU=SHO Users,dc=test,dc=com" and for calling group "CN=Test GRP,CN=Groups,DC=test,DC=com". are these correct?

Comment: You could check the connection string with this tool: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963907.aspx. Just select the object you are interested in and copy the address from the top bar.

Comment: thank you alu , with this app i found the problem and fixed it. there was a error in my ldap query and fixed it. thank you thank you :)

Comment: Great :) I will add the comment to my answer. Can you mark it as solved please?

Answer (score 1):

Try this function:

```
public void AddToGroup(string userDn, string groupDn)
{
    try
    {
        DirectoryEntry dirEntry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + groupDn);
        dirEntry.Invoke("Add", new object[] { userDn });
        dirEntry.CommitChanges();
        dirEntry.Close();
    }
    catch (System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryServicesCOMException E)
    {
        //doSomething with E.Message.ToString();

    }
}
```

To check if the connection string is right you can use the tool [AdExplorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963907.aspx). Just select the object you are interested in and copy the address from the top bar.

Comment: still not working. can you take a look at my LDAP strings. I might doing something wrong.

Comment: If the machine running the application is not in the domain, you need to add the LDAP server in your connection string: `LDAP://server/...`

Comment: my webserver is already joined to the domain and i have the following on my web.config :  <add key="DefaultActiveDirectoryServer" value="192.168.1.1"/>